# CMake cross-compile a custom project for ARMV5

Tags: cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I'm struggling with a cross-compilation problem for one of my cmake-based C++ projects.

My project makes use of many external libraries. I've managed to build and install a number of them in the target environment (which is sshfs-mounte: every time I build a library, I immediately install it on the target), like Boost, Glog, Protobuf, Gtest and so on.

The problem arises when it comes to building my own project and it seems related to the use of the variable `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`.

In facts, some of the dependencies I've built and installed are in `$TARGET_FS/usr/lib` and some more are in `$TARGET_FS/usr/local/lib`. I seem not able to let cmake find all of them by making use of the aforementioned variable.

I'm currently making use of a cross-compilation cmake file, `toolchain-arm.cmake`, with the following contents:

```
SET(TARGET_CC arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.6) 
SET(TARGET_CXX arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.6)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__  -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -Wa,--noexecstack")
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TARGET_CC})
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TARGET_CXX})
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${TARGET_FS}/usr/local")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY) 
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

I invoke cmake process by issuing the following command

```
cmake -DTARGET_FS=<path/to/target/fs> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=optimized -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../Cross/toolchain-arm.cmake  ../../
```

CMake complains about some missing dependencies: the ones living in `${TARGET_FS}/usr/lib` (note that my hint for the compiler in `find_root_path` is about `${TARGET_FS}/usr/local/lib`, so I somewhat expect this behaviour). I would need a way to specify multiple paths to the `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`, but simply separating them with a space and enclosing them between double quotes seems not to be the way to go (`SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${TARGET_FS}/usr/local ${TARGET_FS}/usr")`).

Does anyone have any hints about the way to face this issue?

---

Edit Answering to sergey's comment

Current setup gives this output

```
Boost Libraries Found:
$TARGET_FS/usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.so;
$TARGET_FS/usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.so;
$TARGET_FS/usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so;
$TARGET_FS/usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so;
$TARGET_FS/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so;
$TARGET_FS/usr/local/lib/libboost_signals.so;
$TARGET_FS/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so;
pthread
Boost Includes Found: $TARGET_FS/usr/local/include
COMPILER IS is /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.6
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is optimized
Building HAL, platform is: X86
  -- Found PROTOBUF: $TARGET_FS/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so 
  -- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H
  -- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H - found
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found 
  -- Found Threads: TRUE 

 CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
 Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
 CRYPTO++
     linked by target "<target_1>" in directory <directory_1>
 DUMBNET
     linked by target "<target_2>" in directory <directory_2>
 JSONCPP
     linked by target "<target_3>" in directory <directory_3>
 NET
     linked by target "<target_4>" in directory <directory_4>
 SNMP_LIB
     linked by target "<target_5>" in directory <directory_5>
 UHD
     linked by target "<target_6>" in directory <directory_6>
```

---

Edit 2 (solved?)

Something weird has just happened: I am totally sure I had already given it a try, but now setting the root directory of the target filesystem as `TARGET_FS` (with neither `/usr` nor `/usr/local` appended) allows cmake to find all the required paths. It might be some previous cmake run residual cache which prevented this from working?

Comment: issue is not clean. could you please provide cmake output? also AFAIR CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is a list of directories, so you should use set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${TARGET_FS}/usr/local" "${TARGET_FS}/usr"). refer here for NOTES http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:list

Comment: Yes. It sometimes happens if you not delete CMakeCache after editing CmakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

I went with something like this and specified the search path. You could point the path to your cross compiled libraries.

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH}
              /lib
              /usr/lib
              /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
              /usr/local/lib)

find_library(LIBSSL NAMES libssl.so PATHS)

add_executable(myapp ${myapp_SRC} )

if(LIBSSL )
  message(STATUS ${LIBSSL})
  target_link_libraries(myapp
            ${LIBSSL} )
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "FATAL ERROR: missing library")
endif()
```